# rendersubtree invisible vs hidden or display none

Tags: html, css

Could anyone give an example of the `rendersubtree` in HTML markup and CSS, and explain what is the difference between `rendersubtree = 'invisible'` and `'hidden'` or `display:none`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display:none` works exactly like `rendersubtree` attribute in saving rendering cost. The difference is that it breaks browser features like *Find* & *Print*. But with `rendersubtree` the browser knows that the DOM is hidden only for performance benefits and includes it in its visible DOM features.

For more details https://github.com/WICG/display-locking/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thanks a lot and pls see here - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315171/rendersubtree-for-loading-a-large-amount-of-images-at-once`