# rendersubtree for loading a large amount of images at once?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a lot of images (40.000) on server and their references inside a db table - name, size, date, description etc.

Tried to load all images at once and only 100 of them to be visible, the rest are hidden by css - `display:none` and become visible by scrolling down.

Result - page loading takes too long and new images becomes visible very slow.

So I go back to the old method - pagination - loading images in steps, clicking on `next-prev` buttons.

Now I see a new chrome feature - [rendersubtree](https://github.com/WICG/display-locking/blob/master/README.md)

Could this thing be a solution to load all 40.000 images at once and make them visible by scrolling fluently?

If yes - pls any code example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends why your page is slow. If you're using display:none to hide a whole bunch of content, rendersubtree is unlikely to help in that case.

There's also an img decode API which might help in your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode

But before you jump in there, I would recommend doing some profiling to figure out exactly which part of the process is slow. (img loading / layout / etc)